# Is there an analysis/whitepaper out there regarding RCE with ICMP Echos against windows hosts?

Tags: vulnerability

I know this might sound silly but given what happened with SIGRed I wanted to ask and see what those who know think:

Is there an audit or analysis out there showing the possibility of RCE with ICMP Echos against Windows hosts?

I mean, SIGRed was found to be present since Windows Server 2003...so, there might be a possibility for something like it (with the same implications as EternalBlue) to be present.

Comment: Ping usually refers to ICMP echo, but the vulnerability you refer to is about DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I meant that. Do we know how Windows handles/processes them?

Comment: Although the Windows source code is not available to the public, I do believe we've extensively reverse engineered at least enough of the network stack to understand its handling of ICMP. It's very unlikely that an RCE exists exploitable over only ICMP echo (I'm not aware of any in the past), although there was, a long time ago, a "ping of death" that would cause a non-exploitable _crash_. ICMP is one of the simplest protocols. Any RCE exploitable simply by sending a unsolicited packet to a Windows computer is more likely to exploit a stateful firewall or something, not a simply ICMP echo.

Comment: Any papers or link to discussion regarding that reverse engineering?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not much of a Windows person, so I don't have any. All I know is that Windows is not _that_ hard to reverse engineer (it's just really big), and the networking stack is pretty small. I'd be astounded if it hasn't been extensively reverse engineered, but I have no material to back that view.

Comment: Is there are reason you focus exactly on ICMP echos and not for example other ICMP or ICMPv6 or abnormal IP packets in general etc? This looks for me like a very narrow focus on possible attack vectors, i.e. not looking at the IP stack in general but focus only at some tiny detail of it and ignore everything else.

Comment: Oh no. Not really. I guess I was just focused on ICMP Echos. But if there is any research showing potential RCE with any other part of the IP stack what would be extremely cool